# Matlab Code about trajectory

Tags: matlab

I am making a code about projectile with friction. I think that I made some mistakes but I can't find it out. It is a MATLAB function called targetangle.m that calculates the optimal targeting angle θ for the weapon given the launching speed vs , target distance d and desired accuracy e .

---

```
 function[ theta dif ] = targetangle(vs,d,e)

     % Input the initial condition:

     th = 1:0.1:45;

     for theta=th 

         k = 0.2;

         g = 9.81;

         dt = 0.001;

         the = theta * pi/180.;

         u(1) = vs * cos(the);

         v(1) = vs * sin(the);

         % Launch pad location:

         x(1) = 0.;

         y(1) = 0.;

         for t=1:1:6000;

             u(t+1) = u(t)- dt * (k * sqrt(u(t)^2+v(t)^2) * u(t));

             v(t+1) = v(t)- dt * (k * sqrt(u(t)^2+v(t)^2) * v(t) + g);

             x(t+1) = x(t) + u(t) * dt;

             y(t+1) = y(t) + v(t) * dt;

             % Determination of when the object hits ground:

             if y(t+1) < 0

                 dif = min(abs(x(t+1) - d));

                 plot(x,y)

             end

             if y(t+1) < 0;

                 break

             end

         end

         % Once object hits terminate the computations with a break:

         if y(t+1) < 0; 

             break

         end

     end

     if dif < e

         disp(dif)

     else

         theta = NaN

     end
```

---

when you input like this:

```
vs = 100;

d = 12;

e = 1;

[ theta dif ] = targetangle(vs,d,e)
```

The output should be:

```
theta =

    4

dif =

    0.0323
```

But my code output is :

```
theta =

    NaN


theta =

    NaN


dif =

    3.6718
```

Comment: This question is problematic, as it is NOT a clear problem statement. Especially reading the second half of your code I have no more idea what it *should* do. Maybe you can clearly state what you were trying to do.

Comment: @bdecaf Though the code is a little unclear, the post very well describes the problem: _It is a MATLAB function called targetangle.m that calculates the optimal targeting angle θ for the weapon given the launching speed vs , target distance d and desired accuracy e ._

Comment: @Anson, there is some truth in what he said, though, for future questions please do not highlight that your are a beginner, but what you are having trouble with. Furthermore, describe your goal more detailed. And make your code more readable by using Tabs, speaking names for your variables or comments, and follow a consequent line with where you are inserting a semicolon...

Comment: You are probably right, for recommending an elegant and performant solution, additional information would have been necessary

Comment: I am sorry. I've already  put up explanations.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your calculations is, that you do not save the optimal result during your for-loop. So your result is the (very correct) result of your last loop cycle.

For theta = 45 deg you get theta=NaN because you say so in the last if clause. (btw: the missing semicolon is the reason you get theta printed twice)

You need to store your optimal results in extra variables, e.g. Theta_opt, dif_opt etc. :

```
function[ theta_opt, dif_opt ] = targetangle(vs,d,e)

 % Input the initial condition:

 th = 1:0.1:45;

 k = 0.2;

 g = 9.81;

 dt = 0.001;

 u = 0:.1:599;

 v = 0:.1:599;

 theta_opt = 1;

 dif_opt = 100;

 for theta=th 

     the = theta * pi/180.;

     u(1) = vs * cos(the);

     v(1) = vs * sin(the);

     % Launch pad location:

     x(1) = 0.;

     y(1) = 0.;

     for t=1:1:6000;

         u(t+1) = u(t)- dt * (k * sqrt(u(t)^2+v(t)^2) * u(t));

         v(t+1) = v(t)- dt * (k * sqrt(u(t)^2+v(t)^2) * v(t) + g);

         x(t+1) = x(t) + u(t) * dt;

         y(t+1) = y(t) + v(t) * dt;

         % Determination of when the object hits ground:

         if y(t+1) < 0

             dif = min(abs(x(t+1) - d));

             if(dif < dif_opt)
                 theta_opt = theta;
                 dif_opt = dif;
                 x_opt = x;
                 y_opt = y;
             end

             break

         end

         % Once object hits terminate the computations with a break:

         if y(t+1) < 0; 

             break

         end

     end

 end

 plot(x_opt, y_opt);

 if dif_opt < e

     disp(dif_opt)

 else

     theta_opt = NaN;

 end
```

Comment: Thx. I learnt a lot from your explanation. This time the output is close. theta = 3.4000 dif = 0.0347